# Сравнение файловых систем

Tags: файловая-система

Почему для сетевого хранилища данных используется преимущественно файловая система ext4, а не NTFS??? Подскажите хотя-бы в какую сторону копать

Comment: Копать в сторону какая на сетевых хранилищах используется ОС? Сильно сомневаюсь, что там Вынь

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да и NTFS устарел вроде, или я путаю ?

Comment: Ext4 это фс линукса. Линукс бесплатный поэтому используется на серверах чаще винды

Comment: О каких «сетевых хранилищах» речь, и откуда информация, что ext4 используется преимущественно? Например, в моем «зоопарке» используется ZFS, NTFS, а в качестве «транспорта» - SMB, NFS, iSCSI.

Comment: Речь идет о простом Network-attached storage с RAID.